# Beautifulsoup 4 .find_all() stopped working abruptly

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to create an automated scientific literature collector, that uses google scholar.
All was going well, I was getting the results I wanted, but suddenly something broke and now, despite the data going into soup, it returns everything empty after the first .find_all(). Strangely enough, this does not happen when using a pre-downloaded .htm file.

My code:

```
site=requests.get(url)
site1=site.text
soup=bs(site1, 'html.parser')
ri=soup.find_all("div", class_='gs_ri')
```

Previously ri returned 10 pieces of html code from which further processes would separate everything I needed, but today morning, for reasons beyond my comprehension, it started returning empty, as well as the previous version which I did not touch. I can follow the pipeline up until

```
soup=bs(site, 'html.parser')
```

but not afterwards. 'Soup' still returns everything in order.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are scraping a website then you can't expect the html to stay the same

Comment: Also provide a working example, so we can test code when helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `requests.get(URL)` to extract the information from a website and pass the object to `BeautifulSoup` and extract the content, not the text.

Like this:

```
page = requests.get(URL, timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
ri = soup.find_all("div", class_='gs_ri')
```

**Edit**: You want to use the content, because you want to pass the raw byte stream to BeautifulSoup. `page.text` only returns a string which can cause malfunctions.

Comment: Please provide additional information, why it should need to *extract the content, not the text* and check if this really fixes the issue.

Comment: I tried what you said, but ri still returns empty. It used to work properly in the configuration above anyways, until it didn't.

Comment: Thinking about it, this might be more of a 'requests' error, than a bs4 error, given that the analysis still goes through with a pre-downloaded .htm
The previous, less fancy version should still work though, which it doesn't.